# Closure: How do you tactfully answer when someone asks if you're shopping around, when you are?

Tags: discussion

I remain unsure why  https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/q/8156/2423 was closed as 'unclear'? How ought I clarify?

The title is clear. The body is too; I explained how each of all the possible answers aren't tactful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was one of the community members who voted to delete this question. The reason for this is that you re-posted the same question that was voted closed as unclear earlier -- as @Magisch astutely pointed out.

You should not re-post a question that was, in the past, found to be faulty by the community -- unless conditions have changed and you properly explain why in your updated post.

If you think the original, older post should not have been closed, then do one or more of the following:

- Directly repair the question as indicated in the comments made back then. This will allow a relook so the post can be possibly reopened.
- Discuss it with others who care about the issues in chat.
- Make an IPS Meta post on the original question, and not on the duplicate question. (I am assuming you did not do so back then, as you are asking now on the duplicate.)
- If the community finds this question as unsuitable for this site, please accept that, and use other sources of information to address your concerns.

Comment: Thanks. I've posted another Meta post about the original post.